# jQuery "this-reference" not set after load event

Tags: javascript, this

I don't understand why the "this-reference" in function foo
is not set with #searchval, when called by load event ?

The function call of foo at the keyup event works but the call does not work at the load event cause this-reference is not set.

Example:

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?=$_POST['test']?>" id="searchval">
<select id="names" size="3">
<option value="1">WTF1</option>
<option value="2">WTF2</option>
<option value="3">WTF3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var names = $('#names option').clone();

    function foo() {
        //Change the code to $('$searchval').val(); make it work
        var val = $(this).val(); 
        $('#names').empty();
        names.filter(function(idx, el) {
            return val === '' || $(el).text().indexOf(val) >= 0;
        }).appendTo('#names');
    }
    $('#searchval').bind('keyup', foo);
    $('#searchval').load(foo());
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you notice you are instantly calling `foo` instead of passing it to `.load`. And it looks like you should understand that since you got it right with the `"keyup"` handler.

Comment: FYI, the value of `this` within a particular function execution is called the "*context*" in which the function runs.  So you could (if desired) rephrase your question as, "Why is `foo` not running in the context I expect?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting up the handler with the **return value** from "foo", not the function itself.

It should be:

```
$('#searchval').load( foo );
```

When you pass `foo()`, you're first invoking the function — that's what `( )` does. By passing just the function reference you get the effect you want.

*edit* — on top of that issue, as noted in a comment you're trying to set up a "load" handler for an element that'll never get such an event. What is it that you expect to cause that event?  Perhaps "change" is what you want instead of "load".

*edit again* — if you just want to *simulate* having "foo" called as it is when a "keyup" event happens, you can do two things:

1. You can use "triggerHandler":

   ```
   $('#searchval').triggerHandler('keyup');
   ```
2. You can use "call":

   ```
   foo.call($('#searchval')[0]);
   ```

In both cases, of course, you won't get an "event" object that's like the one you get on a real event, but "foo" doesn't care about that anyway.

Comment: $('#searchval').load( foo ); this code does not call the function foo anymore

Comment: @Blitzmeister there is no `"load"` event for `input` elements. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I want is that the "this-reference" refers at the "load-event" to the same element as for the "keyup-event".

Comment: @Blitzmeister the thing is that "load" events are never sent to `<input>` elements

Comment: Ok, I understand that I can't use input elements...but how can I call the function foo at the load-event with same affect by as called by keyup-event ?